# How to show the tab according to the day?

Tags: android, tabs

I am new to the android and making a simple app to show the class routine. I have used tabs to show the class schedule.Now I need to show the tab of the current day without selecting the tab manually?
i.e.
If today is Monday show the class MonFragment itself.

Answer (score 0):

This approach may also help.

```
   switch (day) {
        case 0:
           actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(0);
            break;
        case 1:


            break;
        case 2:


            break;
        case 3:

            break;
         case 4:
             ............
        default:
            break;
        }
```